# Adding OnClickListener on EditText makes next and done button not working anymore

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have several EditText displaying in a RelativeLayout to collect data from the user. 
They are declared like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/accountNameEdit"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
```

Every EditText has its validation logic, and when the input is wrong an error message is displayed. When a user clicks again on the text field with errors, the error message should disappear, so I added an OnClickListener on the EditText like this:

```
accountName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountNameEdit);
accountName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        accountName.setError(null);
    }
});
```

This is working as expected, however the next and done buttons on the soft key don't work anymore, so the user has to click back to lose focus over the EditText.

First of all, is setting an OnClickListener the best approach or should I hook to another event? How do I get back the original behaviour of the soft key buttons?

I'm compiling against 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add TextWatcher and you can remove the error popup when the user enters something

```
accountName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             accountName.setError(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```